# Config firewall for API

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to develop an API with an authentication system.
But the response of my default route / always display the source code of the Symfony default welcome page instead of no route found or authentication required. What's wrong with my config.

**my security.yaml file** :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login
            logout:
                path: /api/logout
                success_handler: api.logout.success.listener

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

**My SecurityController** :

```
/**
 * @Route("/api")
 */
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="api", methods={"GET"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'test'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        return $this->json([
            'username' => $user->getUsername(),
            'roles' => $user->getRoles(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout", methods={"GET"})
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        // controller can be blank: it will never be executed!
        throw new Exception('Don\'t forget to activate logout in security.yaml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, I finally added a DefaultController with default route "/" that throw a NotFoundException.